# Core Data: why I can't fetch anything with my predicate

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Is there something wrong with the code? I can fetch nothing using this predicate. Comment out the predicate then I can fetch all objects from entity "BankDetail". So I think problem resides in these two lines.

```
// self.bankInfo.name is set in prepareForSegue in first view controller
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"info.name = %@",self.bankInfo.name];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

My model includes two entities, which are in one-to-one relationship

BankInfo.h

```
@class BankDetail;

@interface BankInfo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * city;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * state;
@property (nonatomic, retain) BankDetail * detail;

@end
```

BankDetail.h

```
@class BankInfo;

@interface BankDetail : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * closeDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * updateDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * zip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * acquiringInstitution;
@property (nonatomic, retain) BankInfo * info;

@end
```

**EDIT:**

To provide more detail:

- `self.bankInfo.name` is definitely set, I NSLog it right before the line of predicate
- And I do this in `viewDidLoad`:

  ```
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"BankDetail" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  NSLog(@"[entity description] is %@",[entity description]);
  ```

Get this in console:

```
info = "(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x6d3eb30>), name info, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity BankDetail, renamingIdentifier info, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, destination entity BankInfo, inverseRelationship detail, minCount 1, maxCount 1, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 2";
```

**EDIT2:**
Turn out there's **nothing wrong with the predicate**. The bug is caused by a careless mistake elsewhere (see the accepted answer, it's about renaming). Please IGNORE this post if you have question about predicate.

Comment: I edited the post to show the model

Comment: Have you verified than you do, in fact, have a `BankDetail` object in your `NSManagedObjectContext` that should fulfill this predicate?

Comment: When I comment out the predicate, all `BankDetail` objects get displayed. So the context does have BankDetail objects.

Comment: why would you ask if something is wrong with your code when it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix the bug. It's not about the predicate at all. I rename the entity from `BankDetails` to `BankDetail` in .xcdatamodeld in Xcode editor by simply hit return key and change it, like renaming any other file.

Then I go ahead to manually rename various parts in the auto generated NSManagedObject subclass files, and in other class files that reference it, until all warnings go away. I think I have renamed all that are necessary, but I wasn't. The program doesn't run as I expect like I described in the question, but no error, no warning, Xcode just compile and run.

After some time, when I finally try to regenerate the subclass files to fix the bug, the old `BankDetails` shows up as class name, and lots of naming errors come out. I thought it was some bug of Xcode at first. So I clean the build and regenerate subclass files again. Yet, it's still the good old `BankDetails`. After a few attempts, I found the problem in Data Model Inspector (see screenshot below). Change the Class name and everything runs perfectly.

Moral: always rename in extreme caution!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's a one-to-one relationship, and you already have the `self.bankInfo.name` string that you want to match, why don't you fetch the `BankInfo` object with that name and access that object's `.detail` property? That's the whole point of having a relationship, no?

However, your predicate should work. What is `self.bankInfo` though? Are you sure that `self.bankinfo.name` is a valid string?

Comment: You're definitely right. Since it's one-to-one relationship, no need for FRC AT ALL for second table view controller. Just get the corresponding bankDetail object by relationship to a bankInfo object in first view controller's `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: ChrisH, you get the bounty for confirming the predicate is indeed valid, and for suggesting a simpler approach to access `.detail` through relationship. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate structure is OK.  See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12617712/1347502) for a simple project to prove the basic principle.

Based on responses to other answers it sounds like you are passing this `NSFetchRequest` to a `NSFetchedResultsController` and using its behavior to determine that your predicate doesn't work.

My first suggestion would be to log the predicate and see if it is as expected:

```
NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
```

If that is OK, then in order to test the theory that the predicate is not working you should execute the `NSFetchRequest` directly immediately after building the request, and inspect the results  e.g.

```
// self.bankInfo.name is set in prepareForSegue in first view controller
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"info.name = %@",self.bankInfo.name];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *results = [myMangedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

If that doesn't shed light on the issue then I would suggest the that you remove the predicate from the request, execute the request, and use the following log statements to inspect the full results:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.bankInfo.name);
NSLog(@"%@", [results valueForKeyPath:@"info.name"]);
```

The last log statement actually logs an array of all the bank names so you can see if the value in `self.bankInfo.name` is present in the full results as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have to use a not-so-elegant workaround. I end up adding a `name` attribute for `BankDetail` too. So one BankInfo.name corresponds to one BankDetail.name. Then I use predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",self.bankInfo.name];
```

And it does what I want: fetch one `BankDetail` object for corresponding `BankInfo` object. I wonder it's the best practice at all..

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your predicate as far as I see. I have a very similar one in my app and it works fine:

```
@class Hospital;

@interface Patient : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Hospital *hospital;

@end
```

And

```
@class Patient;

@interface Hospital : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *patients;

@end
```

My predicate:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hospital.name = %@", self.hospital.name];
```

So there's nothing wrong with your code. The problem must be because either `self.bankInfo` or `self.bankInfo.name` are null, or because there's nothing in `info` in your `BankDetail` object (the relationship was not set).

Comment: `self.bankInfo.name` is not null. Please see my edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The predicate code you originally posted is correct.  Below is a quick test project that tests the basic principle: (correctly logs "bank name")

```
// Xcode 4.5:
// Create a new iOS Master-Detail project called "BankInfoTest" tick the "Use Core Data" check box (and ARC).
// Delete all files except the AppDelegate and the BankInfoTest data model (leave supporting files).
// Delete all properties and methods from AppDelegate.h
// Paste this code into AppDelegate.m
// Delete the default entity from the data model
// Add "BankInfo" entity, add attribute "name" of type string.
// Add "BankDetail" entity, add relationship called "info" to BankInfo (leave default 1 to 1 type).
// On BankInfo entity add inverse relationship "detail" to BankDetail (leave default 1 to 1 type).
// Select both entities then select "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass" to create subclasses.
// Run.

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BankDetail.h"
#import "BankInfo.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Setup the core data stack.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BankInfoTest" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    NSURL *appDocsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSURL *storeURL = [appDocsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"BankInfoTest"];

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:nil];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Load some test data and reset the context.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    BankDetail *detailObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BankDetail" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    BankInfo *infoObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    infoObject.name = @"bank name";
    detailObject.info = infoObject;

    [context save:nil];
    [context reset];

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Test the Predicate
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"BankDetail"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"info.name = %@", @"bank name"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    BankDetail *fetchedObject = [results lastObject];
    NSLog(@"%@", fetchedObject.info.name);

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: added another idea to log predicate input and all results ^^^

Comment: added suggestion to switch on core data debugging ^^^

Comment: Are you still interested in debugging the problem in the original question or are you just going to solve the issue with a different approach as per @ChrisH 's answer?  It may still be worth resolving the original issue as it would make this question and answer more useful to others that may have the same underlying problem whatever that turns out to be.  If so I would be interested to see what results you get from the logging statements suggested above and the SQL output.

Comment: Moved debugging suggestions to a separate answer

Comment: Thank you Rory, I finally fix the problem. Please check my answer.

Comment: You're welcome Phillip.... Although I seem to have ended up with a grand total of -2 points for all my suggestions, so I can't have been very helpful in the end. :-)

Comment: Sorry about that.. That's not fair. I just voted you up for your comment and another answer, of which suggestions I did try out accordingly. As for this answer, I think it makes things more complicated than it could be. But again, thanks for your effort:)

Comment: No problem, just to be clear this answer is just the minimum stand-alone code that tests the question you asked.  "Is there something wrong with my predicate?".  You can follow the steps listed at the top and in 5 minutes set up a project that **proves** that the predicate is OK. (as opposed to just saying "I think it looks ok")  I often do this with difficult problems to isolate the issue.  You may find this approach useful yourself. When you prepare a short sample that demonstrates an error you often solve the error, or if not you have a concise example to post for assistance.

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be the use of the `=` operator in the predicate string.

According to the documentation the `LIKE` operator is used for string comparisons, e.g.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"info.name like %@",self.bankInfo.name];
```

The documentation also gives an example of traversing a relationship in the predicate so you should be able to achieve your desired result.  From the `NSPredicate` documentation:

> You can create predicates for relationships, such as:
>
> - group.name like "work*"