# NSPredicate with NSSet of NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a fetch request as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest *songRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Song"];
```

I also have an NSSet of Genre (NSManagedObjects) called genreFilter.

I want to set up a predicate to filter songs that have relationships to the genres in genreFilter.

Could I set up an NSPredicate in this manner:

```
NSPredicate *songRequestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"genre IN %@", [_genreFilter allObjects]];
```

?

Genres look like this:

```
@interface Genre : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *preset;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *song;
@end
@interface Genre (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPresetObject:(Preset *)value;
- (void)removePresetObject:(Preset *)value;
- (void)addPreset:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePreset:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addSongObject:(Song *)value;
- (void)removeSongObject:(Song *)value;
- (void)addSong:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSong:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

and songs like this:

```
@interface Song : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * arousal;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * match;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * popularity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * valence;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * cloud;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Genre *genre;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Year *year;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Period *period;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *yearReleased;

@property (nonatomic, assign) float score;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MPMediaItem *mediaItem;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That looks correct to me.

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12617712/1347502) I gave to another question, it contains simple instructions and code to get a barebones core-data project up and running.  I often use this basic setup to quickly test things like this.

Comment: Well, in that case it looks like the field being compared is a string:
`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"info.name = %@",self.bankInfo.name];`

I was trying to compare an object in a predicate, but I guess that doesn't make much sense, because you can't really express an object as a string.  I should just be taking genre.name in my case, instead of the genre object from the relation.

Thank you for answering, btw!

Comment: No, you can compare objects!  Your predicate looks fine to me...  My example was given only to provide steps to quickly create a basic core-data project that you could use (amending where necessary) to test your predicate.  If you are posting the question because your code doesn't work then you could use this project, amended to test your predicate to isolate the problem.  If you find the simple project works then you know your predicate is ok and your problem is else where.  Once again, your predicate looks ok, you can compare objects, setting up a small project may help debug thats all..

Comment: It would take about 5 minutes to setup, create simple objects with just the relationship you need to test and paste in your predicate, confirm its ok and then look elsewhere for the problem.  If it doesn't work then it will only be something simple that is wrong as it looks good to me.

Comment: Oh, great!  Well, I'm going to give it a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  It works!  I hadn't had a chance to try it out until just now.